# Unable to unlock user in Gnome Setting

Tags: 18.04, gnome

[image: unlock button is not working]

I can't edit other users here, unlock button is not working. I use gnome sessions for xorg by installing the gnome-session package from the repository. In `/var/crash` directory I found `_usr_lib_policykit-1_polkitd.0.crash` file, is this the problem? How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Ita, I still have your same problem. Hope this gets a better brain than mine. But here is only a workaround solution to the unlock button in Ubuntu 20.04 NOT working.

Opening the Gnome control center from a terminal window solves the user unlock issue, but the terminal window logs many critical warnings... maybe telling a smarter brain than mine can determine a better solution. Here goes:

Ollie shared the following related solution to another settings failing to even open.  Because the gnome-control-center might need reinstalling/updating. Open your terminal and type these commands:

```bsh
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-control-center
```

And then the command for opening the display, and system settings, respectively, would be:

```bsh
gnome-control-center display
gnome-control-center
```

You might want to run the `apt-get update` command again after reinstalling the gnome-control-center.

Unfortunately, this solution only works from a terminal window.  Going back to the built-in Settings, returns us back to the inability to unlock a user.